# Surface Capabilities -- distinguish between smart displays and mobile devices

Tags: actions-on-google

My Actions on Google app has screen output with suggestion chips. On a smartphone the chips -- which are displayed as a single row at the screen bottom -- do not fit the screen width. On e.g. a Google Nest Hub they are all visible.

Is there a way to set the chip text according to the screen type? For instance, in that case I would show '(backward)' and '(forward)' on the Nest Hub and '(<<)' and '(>>)' on the smartphone.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER` capability, which exists on phones and not smart displays.

However, from a design perspective, suggestion chips are intended to be available on a scrolling horizontal plane. If the text does not fit on the screen, users are given a visual hint that they can scroll sideways to find additional options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's a nice one. For now, this is a solution I can use. Unfortunately, this will also display the small chips on 'real' web browsers on a PC, where it is not necessary.